# Changing margin on hover shifts all the things beneath it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have created a simple animation using CSS which is that when I hover over an image the margin of the image decreases so as to give a going up effect but the problem coming is that when I change the margin, all the things beneath it also move. How can I only move the image and not the whole?

CSS:

```
.down_arrow {   
    margin: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
}

.down_arrow:hover {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row text-center" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <img src="img/down_arrow.png" class="down_arrow" onclick="goToByScroll('ideas_section');" />
</div>
```

Here's what's happening: [jSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fQpBV/)

Comment: shits all the things? :)

Comment: Adjust the bottom margin as well, or change the relative position of the element instead of the margin.

Comment: If you want to use margin-top, then you’ll have to modify the margin-bottom in the same fashion. Better to use relative positioning instead, and transition the `top` property: http://jsfiddle.net/fQpBV/8/

Comment: Give `margin-bottom:28px;`

Answer (score 2):

Give it a position and animate that instead of the margin:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fQpBV/9/)

```
  .down_arrow {   
        margin: 15px;
        top:0;
        position:relative;
        -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: top 0.5s ease-out;
    }

    .down_arrow:hover {
        top: -12px;
    }
```

Comment: Seems to solve it to me. What's still wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Add au div with à fixed height arroud the img.

```
<div class="row text-center" style="margin-top: 30px; height: 100px;">
    <img src="img/down_arrow.png" class="down_arrow" onclick="goToByScroll('ideas_section');" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an updated `fiddle`. appropriately set the bottom padding/margin too on hover

http://jsfiddle.net/fQpBV/6/

Comment: Please (always) post some relevant code directly in your answer

Comment: I'm using Chrome -- the text shifts up by a pixel at the start of the animation, then down by the same distance at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust the bottom margin to compensate:

http://jsfiddle.net/fQpBV/12/

```
.down_arrow:hover {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
}
```

Comment: While this solution works, it also causes the text below the image to wobble unattractively due to the asymmetric easing on the animation.

Comment: @Blazemonger Odd, which browser?  Fine in FF. Both properties are being animated the same number of pixels.  Surprised it's not clean in all browsers.

Comment: I'm using Chrome -- the text shifts up by a pixel at the start of the animation, then down by the same distance at the end. It's the easing that causes it; anything except `linear` will usually have the same result.

Comment: @Blazemonger Weird.  I actually have a similar issue with the relative approach in FF.  The image has some weird effect at the start and end of the animation.